# Android: cannot write on to applications outputstreams

Tags: java, android, outputstream

I am making  a proxy server in android .

But I got some problem .It compile and execute but in the phone the code to write on the outputstream of applications  has no effects. the inputstream work normally but when i do

```
BufferedOutputStream bo =new BufferedOutputStream(new outputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

bo.write(message);
bo.flush();
```

it does nothing. I need your help. thanks

Comment: Can you post some code, and stackstraces to help people understand what's going on.

Comment: Please rephrase your problem as your app cannot write to an output stream of a socket. Applications dont have streams like that. And it is not Android but your app that has the problem.

Comment: ok i will get code and trace

Comment: it shows no errors but it has no effects      <br>

Comment: sorry i am new here so i dont know how to paste the code here.  and the page give me no explication on how to do

Comment: don t know how to post code